# How to deploy existing application to the Divio Cloud

Tags: django-cms, divio

I have django-cms application and I want to deploy it to the Divio cloud and really can't understand from the docs how to do it. I understand how to start new application using divio cli but not how to deploy existing.

Answer (score 1):

The specifics of how to deploy an existing application to Divio Cloud vary widely based on the application structure itself. Basically Divio Cloud allows to deploy any web application which can be packaged in a Docker image.

There is some documentation about the process of migrating an existing Django application to Divio Cloud here: http://divio-cloud-developer-handbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to/migrate-existing-project.html